# Average in three dimensional array every 12 step for third dimension

Tags: arrays, r, average

I have the array `a`

```
dim (a) 
[1] 126 59 240
```

I would like to calculate the average of third dimension every 12 step.
I tried with:

```
rollapply(a,3,mean,by=12 )
```

but the result is a vector of length 11 and no more.

It is better `apply` and a specific function?
My expected result is a new array with `dim 126 59 20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definetly not straightforward but it works.

```
a = array(1:(126*59*240),c(126,59,240))          # Dummy data
s = seq(1,240,by=12)                             # Sequence of cutpoints for 3rd dim
aux =lapply(s,function(x){
  apply(a[,,x:(x+11)],c(1,2),mean,na.rm=TRUE)    # Get list with mean per each 12 3rd dim
})

aux2 = do.call(cbind,aux)                        # Bind all elements of list by column
Y = array(aux2,dim=c(dim(aux[[1]]),length(aux))) # Reconvert into array

> dim(Y)
[1] 126  59  20
```

Comment: Tanks boski...one question: How change the result if I try : "aux =lapply(s,function(x){
  apply(a[,,x:(x+11)],3,mean,na.rm=TRUE) })"  # 3 instead of c(1,2) .... Why the correct apply arguments is c(1,2) for the array of 3 dim?